# If $\gcd(a,b)+\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)+\operatorname{lcm}(a,c)$, then are b and c equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Is it true that, if $\gcd(a,b)+\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)+\operatorname{lcm}(a,c)$, then are $b$ and $c$ equal?

For coprime $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$, it is trivial. It is also easy when $a|b$ and $a|c$. I am unable to construct counterexamples. I tried to use the property that $\gcd(a,b)\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$, but to no avail. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Hint: Can you find integers $w, x, y, z$ such that $  a/w + ax  = a/y + az$, with $a$ a multiple of $x$ and $y$? If so, what $b$ and $c$ does that yield?

Comment: @CalvinLin: So they did. Bad reading skills!

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried that, constructed some satisfying values of $gcd(a,b)$ and $LCM(a,b)$, but one of $a,b$ would be non-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save typing let me write $G$ for $GCD$ and $L$ for $LCM$.

From
$$G(a,b)\ |\ G(a,b)+L(a,b)=G(a,c)+L(a,c)$$
and
$$G(a,b)\ |\ a\ |\ L(a,c)$$
it follows that $G(a,b)\ |\ G(a,c)$. Likewise $G(a,c)\ |\ G(a,b)$, so $G(a,b)=G(a,c)$. Hence $L(a,b)=L(a,c)$, and finally
$$ab=L(a,b)G(a,b)=L(a,c)G(a,c)=ac$$
and $b=c$.

Comment: Great! This is from the 'book', though trivial

Answer (score 2):

If $a=0$, then $\gcd(a,b)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\lvert b\rvert$ and $\gcd(a,c)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,c)=\lvert c\rvert$, so we get $2\lvert b\rvert = 2\lvert c\rvert \;\;\to\;\; \lvert b\rvert = \lvert c\rvert$. For $a\neq 0$, rearranging your equation results in

$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) - \operatorname{lcm}(a,c) = \gcd(a,c) - \gcd(a,b) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $a \mid \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ and $a \mid \operatorname{lcm}(a,c)$, this means $a$ divides the LHS above. However, we have $0 \lt \gcd(a,c) \le \lvert a\rvert$ and $0 \lt \gcd(a,b) \le \lvert a\rvert$, so the RHS is $\gt -\lvert a\rvert$ and $\lt \lvert a\rvert$, so since $a$ divides it, this means it must be $0$. Thus, we get

$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \operatorname{lcm}(a,c), \;\; \gcd(a,c) = \gcd(a,b) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using the relationship you mentioned of $\gcd(a,b)\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \lvert ab\rvert$, and \eqref{eq2A} above, gives that

$$\gcd(a,b)\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \lvert ab\rvert = \gcd(a,c)\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(a,c) = \lvert ac\rvert \;\to\; \lvert ab\rvert = \lvert ac\rvert \;\to\; \lvert b\rvert = \lvert c\rvert \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints towards a solution:

1. Show that $ \gcd (a, b) \mid a \mid \operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$.
2. Show that $ w \mid a \mid x$ if and only if we can find a $b$ such that $ \gcd (a, b) = w$ and $ \operatorname{lcm} (a, b) = x$.
3. Thus, a solution exists if and only if we can find $ w \mid a \mid x$ and $ y \mid a \mid z$ with $ w + x = y + z$.
4. Now consider $ |w - y| = |z - x|$. What can we say about the LHS? What can we say about the RHS?
5. Show that under the previous equality, we must have $ |w-y| = |z-x| = 0$. Hence, no distinct solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = \gcd(a, b, c)$. Then $\gcd(a / x, b / x) = \gcd(a, b) / x$, $\operatorname{lcm}(a / x, b / x) = \operatorname{lcm}(a, b) / x$.

So, switching to $a' = a / x$, $b' = b / x$, $c' = c / x$ we get $$\gcd(a', b') + \operatorname{lcm}(a', b') - \gcd(a', c') + \operatorname{lcm}(a', c') = 0$$ with $\gcd(a', b', c') = 1$.

Note that all terms but maybe $\gcd(a', c')$ are divisible by $\gcd(a', b')$, so $\gcd(a', b') | \gcd(a', c')$. But then $\gcd(a', b') | \gcd(a', b', c')$ and thus $\gcd(a', b') = 1$. Similarly, $\gcd(a', c') = 1$.

This reduces general case to coprime $a, b, c$, which you have already solved.

Answer (score 1):

By below $\ ab = \overbrace{(a,b)[a,b] = (a,c)[a,c]}^{\textstyle\ \ \color{#c00}{n\cdot  N\ \ =\ \ m\cdot  M}} = ac\,\overset{\!\div\ a}\Rightarrow\, b=c,\,$  where $\,0 < n,N,m,M\in\Bbb Z$.

**Lemma** $\,\ n,m\mid N,M,\,\ n\!+\!N = m\!+\!M\ \Rightarrow\ n=m \Rightarrow N=M\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{nN = mM}$

**Proof** $\,\ n\mid M,\,n\mid  n\!+\!N\!=\!m\!+\!M\Rightarrow n\mid m\Rightarrow n\le m.\,$ $\underbrace{\rm{symmetry}}_{\large n,N\,\leftrightarrow\, m,M}\!\Rightarrow m\le n,\,$ so $\,n \!=\! m$

Comment: The Lemma shows that the *key idea*  holds more generally.